# pyQt5 execution stops when using pyttsx3 even with Threading

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyttsx3

Hi so essentially I'm writing an application that should provide a GUI along with speech recognition commands and the program should answer in TTS. I wrote a little test program because I wanted to learn threading with pyQt5 as it is needed to keep the GUI responsive - that's my understanding so far and it seems to work unless it tries to TTS.

Now I have the problem that as long as I don't TTS the input, everything works fine. But with pyttsx3, the .runAndWait() function exits the execution of my code.
This is the code in question: (The GUI has the slider to check if the threading works)

```
import sys
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
speaker = pyttsx3.init()
voices = speaker.getProperty('voices')
# speaker.setProperty('voice', voices[33].id)
# speaker.setProperty('rate', 190)

class DlgMain(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")

        self.btnStart = QPushButton("Start")
        self.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.evt_btnStart_clicked)

        self.dial = QSlider()
        self.lcd = QLCDNumber()
        self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.lcd.display)

        self.lytLCD = QHBoxLayout()
        self.lytLCD.addWidget(self.dial)
        self.lytLCD.addWidget(self.lcd)

        self.lytMain = QVBoxLayout()
        self.lytMain.addWidget(self.btnStart)
        self.lytMain.addLayout(self.lytLCD)
        self.setLayout(self.lytMain)

    def evt_btnStart_clicked(self):
        # In this function create an instance of the worker class
        self.worker = WorkerThread()
        self.worker.start()
        # Catching our own "update" signal
        #self.worker.update_progress.connect(self.evt_update_progress)



# Whatever should be run in the thread must now run in the worker class!
class WorkerThread(QThread):
    # Create our own signal to send current info to GUI
    #update_progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):

        global recognizer

        while True:
            try:

                with sr.Microphone(device_index=0) as source:

                    recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=.2)
                    print("Listening...")
                    recognizer.energy_threshold = 4000
                    audio = recognizer.listen(source)

                    print("Recognizing...")
                    message = recognizer.recognize_google(audio).lower()
                    speaker.say(message)
                    speaker.runAndWait()
                    # print(message)

            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                recognizer = sr.Recognizer()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dlgMain = DlgMain()
    dlgMain.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Do I have to give the TTS its own thread? Or can I somehow solve this with a pyqtSignal? I'm really not sure what to even search for and so far have not found a similar question.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try running the program in a terminal or prompt and see if you get some more useful traceback. Also try to create all TTS related objects (`recognizer`, `speaker` and `voices`) in the `run` function.

Comment: Ok, I put the tts stuff into the run function. And ran the program from the terminal. Sadly, this also just closes the application with exit code 0 apparently. No errors no nothing. I am pretty sure that its the runAndWait() function. I found other people with a similar problem, often using tkinter (No solutions there too apparently). I guess Ill try to find a different tts library and hope that this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to work around the problem myself. It was in fact the runAndWait() function from pyttsx3 that was breaking the program. Instead, I now use a combination of gTTS, pydub, soundfile, playsound, and pyrubberband.

The speak function now looks like this:

```py
from gtts import gTTS
from pydub import AudioSegment
import playsound
import soundfile as sf
import pyrubberband as pyrb

def speakMsg(message):

    # Write the message to mp3
    tts = gTTS(text=message, lang="en")
    tts.save("clear_msg.mp3")

    # Change the file to wav format so it can be edited
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("clear_msg.mp3")
    sound.export("clear_msg.wav", format="wav")

    # Make playback faster (and pitch it down)
    data, samplerate = sf.read("clear_msg.wav")
    data_stretch = pyrb.time_stretch(data, samplerate, 1.4)
    data_shift = pyrb.pitch_shift(data_stretch, samplerate, 0)

    # Safe it as new file and play it.
    sf.write("edit_msg.wav", data_shift, samplerate, format='wav')
    playsound.playsound("edit_msg.wav")
```

What looks super unnecessarily complicated is in fact surprisingly performant! And also the program now works :D
You could do this with gTTS only but I figured the gTTS voice was too slow. So I sped it up and lowered the tone so it doesn't get too "chipmunky". That is why I did so much extra!